# HTML to ODT – XSLT?

Tags: java, html, openoffice-writer, odt

I'm trying to convert single pieces of HTML code to the XML Format the *.odt format (Open Office) is using. For example, `<p>This is some text</p>` should be translated to `<text:p>This is some text</text:p>`. Of course, this should also work with lists etc.

I'm not sure whether the best way to go would be using a XSLT processor (and if so, which one for Java?) and create the stylesheet myself – isn't there a Java library out there that can already do this? 
I'm using jodconverter to go from ODT->PDF, but even though OpenOffice Writer can handle copy&pasting the content and display it in the desired way, jodconvert doesn't seem to be able to "translate" single pieces of HTML (or am I wrong about that?).

Any ideas and suggestions would be very welcome. I should add that I'm absolutely new to Java. Thanks in advance
Ingo

Comment: HTML or XHTML? XSLT only works on XML, and HTML isn't XML.

Comment: Thanks. I am in fact talking about HTML, but even if HTML itself isn't XML, it should be possible to "tidy" it up to make it work (as described in the links of Askolein's post).

Comment: Yes it is certainly possible to tidy HTML into XML in some cases. But not always, if the HTML is malformed.

Comment: In this case I can safely assume that the code is "clean" and if it's not safely blame it on the user, since the users will only be colleagues and they should know how to do it right. ;)

Comment: Still, you should acknowledge that you are creating a solution that can fail.

Comment: Yeah, I do. But it would be better than it is right now, the current system is very likely to fail. Robustness sure is a good thing and I'm also looking into another way besides XSLT, but I want to keep this option open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT is the best way to do it. The OpenDocument group is working on a HTML to ODT xsl template. Sadly, it is not ready yet.

You can check [on their website](http://opendocumentfellowship.com/projects/odftools) to stay in touch (and get beta work maybe).

Otherwise, you have non official project, also based on XSLT: [like this one](http://xhtml2odt.org/)
It would be easy to apply a little transformation on your HTML to get a valid XHTML before processing it to ODT.

Or just check [this other example.](http://fisheye.liip.ch/browse/PUB/fluxcms/branches/matrix/inc/bx/editors/ooo/html2odt.xsl?r=9331)

Comment: Thank you, this is great information. I actually stumbled across xhtml2odt.org on my own before, but somehow forgot about it again. I'll wait if other people have input, too, before accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Well looks like there's nothing else to come. For completeness, I will also try using the jodconverter to convert the HTML to an ODT file and then extract the neccessary parts. We suspect that OpenOffice might be using a parser internally already as it is able to deal with copy-pasted HTML. Thanks for your input!